# Mozilla Firefox is not responding (can't launch it)

Tags: windows-7, firefox

I am using firefox 5.0. Windows 7. I left my laptop for a moment then when I get back found it restarted. Since then I can't start firex. Window opens and on the bar is written 'not responding'. I reinstalled the browser, but the problem is there. I checked if windows installed any updates though no new updates. I restarted the laptop many times, but that does not help. What might be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have an add-on that's killing it. Try starting firefox in safe mode. There should be an icon for it in the start menu, or you can open the Run dialogue by pressing Windows key + R and typing

`firefox -safe-mode`

Then disable all add-ons and try starting firefox normally.

Comment: No, I even can't start the browser in safe mode. It shows the message 'not responding'. I disabled and reseted all the features except removing bookmarks. But then the system freezes and the blue screen of death (stop error) appears.

Comment: That sounds a lot more serious. Does this happen with other programs too, or just firefox?

Comment: If you are not trying running firefox then other programs are working, otherwise the system slows down and crashes. Now I am using google's Chrome, for example. By the way, I discovered that Windows nevertheless installed some updates for window defender something related to spyware prevention. But the system does not allow to remove or disable it. I guess that's because of it I have this problem. So I have installed more updates: service pack 1 for windows 7, but that did not help.